# Pyspark: How to avoid python UDF as a driver operation?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a python UDF that needs to be run in a pyspark code, Is there any way of calling that UDF using mappartitions, so that I can avoid that python operation not just run only in the driver node and use the full cluster, because If I just use the UDF directly on the dataframe, that would run as a driver operation, isn't it? What is the efficient way of doing this?

```
class Some_class_name
   def pyt_udf(x):
     <some python operation>
     return data

   def opr_to_be_done:
      df = spark.sql(f'''select col1, col2 from table_name''')
      rdd2=df.rdd.mappartition(lambda x: pyt_udf(x))
```

Comment: UDF operations will be performed by executors. I think there is no need to convert that to rdd and use mappartition, you can register that udf using `spark.udf.register` and use that in your SQL query.

Comment: For example, If I have to pass the dataframe to do some encoding process (Ex: catboost encoding) or some other process that runs on a list of columns, what is the most efficient way to do that? @MohanaBC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mapPartitions in PySpark to apply a Python UDF to an RDD in parallel across the nodes in the cluster. This can be more efficient than applying the UDF directly to a DataFrame, which would be executed on the driver node.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

# Define the schema for the input DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField('col1', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('col2', StringType(), True)
])

# Define the Python UDF
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def python_udf(data):
    # Apply some Python operation to the input data
    result = data.apply(<some python operation>)
    return result

# Create a DataFrame
df = spark.sql("SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_name")

# Convert the DataFrame to an RDD and apply the Python UDF using mapPartitions
rdd = df.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda partition: python_udf(partition.toPandas()))

# Convert the RDD back to a DataFrame
result_df = rdd.toDF(schema)

# Show the result DataFrame
result_df.show()
```